# How can I override how rest-auth saves users?

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

My site has a django backend and it uses [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/) package for authentication. I want to change this function inside rest-auth serializers:

```
path_to_my_virtenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer): 

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', '')
        }
```

I tried editing it directly and everything worked as I wanted, however I have a suspicion that it's not a good idea to edit files inside virtenv site-packages. Is there a way to override them from my django app? What is the best thing to do in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, editing this file is the worst option. You should never edit a third party applications code on your local machine (except you want to test some extreme case).

Django Rest Auth allows you to change Serializer class for all endpoints, you can find it on [documentation](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration).

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution worked perfectly for me.

I wonder though, what can I do if I want to change something inside a third party application that doesn't provide settings for changing its files? Should I fork it on github, change it there and reinstall it? Or should I download its contents and make them into my own app directly on my local machine? Or maybe something else altogether?

Comment: @warpfactorten If it is not an urgent case, then you can ask Application owner to add this feature. But if you don't want to wait for it, you should fork the github and add the feature needed. You can even open a Pull Request to original repo if your work is helpfull for others too. Editing the code in your local machine is not good for many reasons: it stays only in your computer, you can not pack it, it will disappear if there is an update for the application and so on...

Comment: very well explained zeynel, changing third party apps code is extremelly dangerous. At next reinstall of dependencies everything will be gone. And it's impossible to track in git.